# Voice call with gsm-modem by C#

Tags: c#, call, gsm, voice, recording

im new in c# and i wanna right a code for have a voice call through the GSM modem , actually don't know about how to receive and send voice or stream that ,if any one knows about how to do it please help me with this problem.
i just found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fd8acc1-252b-4465-a38b-021b2499518d/problems-retrieving-voice-data-from-voice-modem-using-net-serialport-and-at-commands?forum=netfxbcl) but didn't understand enough to develop my application.
every thing i know is just to send command ,unfortunately i do not even know the AT-Commands.

```
Port gsmPort=new Port();
gsmPort.Name="COM3";
gsmPort.open();
gsmPort.writeLine("AT\r");
```

Comment: Use [ATD] to dial, [ATH] to hangup. Basic AT reference [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164659)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you read these links:

1. http://www.zeeman.de/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/ubinetics-at-command-set.pdf
   2.https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Cellular%20Modules/AT_Commands_Reference_Guide_r0.pdf
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3Vn_YEh3jM